# How to Access Array

Tags: php, json

I am still a beginner in `PHP` and `MySQL` and have come across a complicated array I need some help with.

So far the arrays I have worked with are fairly flat, i.e. 1 row of data with multiple fields, say for example a result based on a single address, so line1, line2, line3, town, etc.

I am now dealing with an external api that returns the following results in xml

```
{"result":
{
group1 [{"fieldname1":"fieldresult1", "fieldname2":"fieldresult2}]
group2 [{"fieldname3":"fieldresult3", "fieldname4":"fieldresult4}] 
}
"message":"OK",
"success":true}
```

My question is how do I access each of the results,

I am planning on using a foreach statement, and will be calling the result $xmlarray.

I then want to define strings such as $field1, $field2, but not sure how to do this when it seems to be quite a deep array, I am guessing something like:

```
$field1 = $array([0]["field2"];
```

As I say, I need someones help just to give me a brief overview here, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This content of you posted Data looks like JSON to me...

so you could try some like

```
$json = json_decode($array);
```

than you could go for

```
$field1 = $json['group1']['fieldname1'];
```

and so on.

[source](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @Simon79 you welcome. May vote up and accept answere :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not `XML`. It is json. Use `json_decode()` for this.

```
$data = json_decode($response); //$response is the response you are getting from the api.
var_dump($data);
```

`$data` will contain the response. The you can access them easily.[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)